# Prove that $f(x+h)-f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x), h\rangle\geq 0 \Rightarrow f $ convex

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

At [this](http://www.math.udel.edu/~angell/Opt/conv_fcn.pdf#page=13) link there is a demonstration that for $f$ continuously differentiable on $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ convex, $f(x+h)-f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x), h\rangle\geq 0 \Rightarrow f $ convex. This argument uses an intermediate step regarding "$x\mapsto \nabla f(x)$ is monotone", which I find tedious, and in general I find that this argument gets lost in alphas and betas and misses the geometry of the situation. Does anyone know a more elegant argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since everything takes place along the line containing $x$ and $x+h$, it is sufficient to show this in one dimension (i.e. w.l.o.g. $n=1$).  Now draw a picture, and it will be visually obvious.

However, to make it a proof, consider
$$ g(x) = \sup\{f(y) + (x-y)f'(y) : y \in C\} $$
By hypothesis $f(x) \ge g(x)$.  By looking at the special case $y = x$ we see that $g(x) \ge f(x)$.  Therefore $f(x) = g(x)$.  And $g(x)$ is the suprema of linear functions, and the suprema of linear functions must be convex.

And now we have a proof in one dimension, we can get a proof in $n$ dimensions:
$$ g(x) = \sup\{f(y) + \langle x-y,\nabla f(y)\rangle : y \in C\} $$

Comment: Hmmm...I am trying to work it out in 1d. Suppose we have that $f(y)-f(x) - f'(x)(y-x) \geq 0$, and we want to show that $$f(x) + t(f(y) - f(x))-f(x+t(y-x))\geq 0$$ for $t\in [0,1]$. The function is zero at $t=0,1$, and its derivative with respect to $t$ is $$f(y)-f(x) -f'(p)(y-x), \tag{1}$$ where $p$ is the intermediate point. We want to show that the function has no crossing, or that (1) can only be zero at a single value $t\in [0,1]$. Ideas?

Comment: Do you see that it is visually obvious?

Comment: In a way I do...the problem is that I need to use the fact that the hypothesis holds at *every* point...this suggests proof by contradiction.

Comment: I suppose I would say it is visually obvious, except that I am having a hard time pinning it down, which makes me think maybe it isn't so visually obvious.

Comment: I edited it to make it a proper proof.

Comment: Very good, elegant argument. Awesome!

Comment: Yes, it wasn't obvious to me as I thought.  But then my experience with Banach spaces, and my memories of the Hahn-Banach Theorem helped me, and saved the day!  Frankly, by saying it is obvious, I pushed myself into a very tight corner, and I am glad I was able to get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible method:

Given any two points $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$, the function is convex on the straight line between them, which is sufficient. This can be shown by observing that $\tilde{f}: t\mapsto  f((1-t)x + ty)$ has non-decreasing derivative on $[0,1]$ (draw a picture), and therefore, it is convex.