# Is the supremum of affine functions convex?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If $f$ is a real valued function and $f=\sup f_n$, for some sequence of functions $f_n$ having the following form: $f_n(x)=a_n+b_n x$, then $f$ is a convex function? Can be proved?

Comment: Yes. The supremum of a sequence of linear functions is convex.

Comment: The answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575312/when-does-it-help-to-write-a-function-as-fx-sup-alpha-phi-alphax is quite enlightening in this respect.